# Define svnSetting globally

Tags: svn, ant, svnant

I would like to define svnSetting globally in my build.xml ant script:

```
<project name="helloworld" basedir="." default="helloworld">
    <svnSetting
        javahl="false"
        svnkit="true"
        username="guest"
        password=""
        id="svn.settings"
    />
    ...
</project>
```

but eclipse says  of course:

> Problem: failed to create task or type svnSetting
>   Cause: The name is undefined.

Is there any possibility I can define svnSetting directly under project and not within targets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `typedef` to your ant script:

```
<project name="helloworld" basedir="." default="helloworld">
    <path id="path.svnant">
        <pathelement location="${basedir}/svnant.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${basedir}/svnClientAdapter.jar"/>
    </path>
    <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml"
             classpathref="path.svnant"/>
```

You can read this [article](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/introduction.html) for more details.

Comment: Args, I already have an typedef BUT I had it below svnSetting... moved svnSetting below typedef and all work now. Thanks!