# svn ant - name is undefined

Tags: svn, ant

I'm trying to update my codebase using ant. I have placed svnant.jar, svnClientAdapter.jar, svnjavahl.jar under ANT_HOME\lib directory. I'm using the bellow code snippet and it gives error.

Problem: failed to create task or type svnSetting
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any `<presetdef>`/`<macrodef>` declarations have taken place.

```
<path id= "svnant.classpath" >
     <fileset dir= "${antlib.dir}" >
         <include name= "*.jar" />
     </fileset>
</path>
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svnant.classpath" /> 

<target name="init-svn">
 <svnSetting svnkit="false" javahl="true" username="***" password="****" id="svn.settings" />    
</target>

<target name="update-source" depends="init-svn">
        <svn refid="svn.settings" >
          <update  dir="${basedir}" revision="HEAD" url="${svn.url}"/>
        </svn>
</target>
```

can someone help me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define svnSetting globally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913561/define-svnsetting-globally)

Comment: defined it globally. still having same issue.

Comment: Checkout the following alternative to the svnant task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305315/the-svn-client-svnkit-is-not-available/16310312#16310312

Answer (score 2):

I guess you didn't defined the property `antlib.dir` anywhere. So here you build an empty classpath for the `taskdef`.

Actually if you put your jars into ANT_HOME\lib, you don't need to build a classpath for your `taskdef`. Just do:

```
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" />
```

And to be sure Ant see your jars correctly, just run `ant -diagnostics`

Comment: I changed the ant file like this:  
I added your changes, but still having same issue. And then removed "init-svn" target including svnSetting. modified the code as bellow.   Now it shows, Cannot find javahl, svnkit nor command line svn client  
    <target name="update-source">
        <svn refid="svn.settings" svnkit="false" javahl="true"  username="***" password="****">
      <update  dir="${basedir}" revision="HEAD" url="${svn.url}"/>
        </svn>
    </target>

Comment: Have you checked your jars are listed by `ant -diagnostics` ?